# CMake link to only release config of target in both debug and release

Tags: cmake

Is there another a way to link only the release lib of a target when including the target with `target_link_libraries` for both release and debug configs.

I know `target_link_libraries` has the options `optimize` and `debug` and that it can be done like this

```
target_link_libraries(current_target
    optimized $<TARGET_PROPERTY:lib_target,IMPORTED_IMPLIB_RELEASE>
    debug $<TARGET_PROPERTY:lib_target,IMPORTED_IMPLIB_RELEASE> 
)
```

However I generally keep the targets in a list

```
set(target_list
    lib_target1
    lib_target2
    ...
)
```

and I perform other things on the same list, like getting the binary directory of the target to include in the search path for debugging. Using the `optimized` and `debug` options also do not allow the lib_target... properties to be passed along through the current_target. I can work around it just curious if there is another way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you link with IMPORTED target, then its configuration-dependent properties refer to "imported configuration". You may always adjust **mapping** between configurations of your project and imported ones:

1. **Global** configuration mapping is adjusted by [CMAKE_MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_<CONFIG>](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/variable/CMAKE_MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_CONFIG.html) *variables*.

   The setting below will use *Release* configuration of every IMPORTED target for **any** of *Release*, *Debug* or *RelWithDebugInfo* configurations of your project:

   ```
    set(CMAKE_MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_RELEASE Release)
    set(CMAKE_MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_DEBUG Release)
    set(CMAKE_MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_RELWITHDEBUGINFO Release)
   ```

Note, that these settings should be issued **before** creating of IMPORTED targets. That is, if such targets are created with `find_package()` calls, the settings should precede these calls.

2. **Per-target** configuration mapping is adjusted by [MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_<CONFIG>](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/prop_tgt/MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_CONFIG.html) *properties*.

   Settings below do the same as global settings above but only for `lib_target1` IMPORTED target:

   ```
    set_target_properties(lib_target1 PROPERTIES
        MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_RELEASE Release
        MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_DEBUG Release
        MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_RELWITHDEBUGINFO Release)
   ```

   These settings can be applied only after given IMPORTED target is created, e.g. after `find_package()` call.

It is worth to mention, that you may also specify *fallback* imported configurations:

```
set(CMAKE_MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_DEBUG Release Debug)
```

With such setting, if your project is built in *Debug* configuration, and some IMPORTED target doesn't have *Release* configuration, then its *Debug* configuration will be used. (But if that target has neither Release nor Debug configuration, CMake will emit an error).